# C# Database context in a multi environment setup

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I am working in a multi environment setup (DEV, TEST, PREPROD, PROD) and need to write tests that can easily be switched between environment (using e.g. environment as input parameter).

My tests need to do database lookups. Currently I have created a DBContext for each environment. 
[Image of solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyh92.png)

Currently my tests are responsible for creating the correct database context

Like so:

```
if (environment.ToLower().Equals("test")) { 
            var arkiv = new TransformContentCenter_TestEntities1();
            var invoicesNotProcesseed = entries
                .Where(row => !arkiv.Brevarkiv.Any(row1 => row1.ReferenceNumber.Equals(row.invoiceNo) && row1.LetterType=="Invoice")).ToList();
```

I am aware that this is poor code style and I am looking for a way to create a database layer that takes care of environment handling. I do however not know which setup is best practise to handle this situation and how to implement it into my solution. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Should your tests really be doing actual database look-ups? just curious.

Comment: @Amn why not? How would you test that? All my db lookups are tested and run on the build sever using SQLite because it supports in memory database. Once deployed the sql server is used.

Comment: Why would you need to run unit tests on multiple environments? You should only need to do that against dev to verify that your application is functioning correctly. Your app should have no concept of environments and should be given the variables it needs at deployment time. Build once and deploy anywhere.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan if you are doing in-memory "db" lookups without having to depend on there being actual connectivity to the real database server during unit testing (which you are but seems that the OP is not), that's fine. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use config file transforms for this.See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

You can  use 3rd party addins (or something like this http://gunnarpeipman.com/2013/11/using-web-config-transforms-with-app-config-files/) to accomplish the same for app.config too.

So you can transform a key/value (like connection string) depending on the build config which you can look for when running tests.